# Formatear entero a decimal

Tags: .net, oracle, decimal, datarow, format

Necito formatear numero que obtengo de mi BD, esto vienen en formato entero (50000, 125055, 64742) y los quiero cambiar a (500.00, 1250.55, 647.42). Estos utilizando la funcion de string.format pero me manda error en los dRow[3],dRow[4],dRow[5]. Intente cambiar el Convert.ToInt32 a Convert.ToInt64 y sigue mandando error.

Este es mi codigo:

```
Params[0] = "p_InEmpresa/32;0:1|" + Empresa.ToString();
 Params[1] = "p_InAnio/16;0:1|" + LstAnios.SelectedValue;
 Params[2] = "p_InOpcion/16;0:1|1";
 Params[3] = "p_cursor/0;0:2|";
 ds = DB.ExecuteStoredProc("SIP2000.PK_EJEMPLO.sp_Historico", Params, 4, ParamsOut);
          
      for (int y = 0; y < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; y++)
      {
        dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y];

        dRow[3] = string.Format("{0:######0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[3].ToString()) / 100.0);
        dRow[4] = string.Format("{0:######0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[4].ToString()) / 100.0);
        dRow[5] = string.Format("{0:######0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[5].ToString()) / 100.0);
       }

            Grid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            Grid1.DataSource = ds;
            Grid1.DataBind();
            ds.Dispose();
```

Error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo convierto a decimal o double me quita los decimales y me los pone de esta forma (500, 1250, 647) lo que esta mal porque espero esto (500.00, 1250.55, 647.42).

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo???

Espero que mis datos traidos de bd (50000, 125055, 64742) se formateen a (500.00, 1250.55, 647.42).

Comment: Lo que entiendo que dice el error, es que esa columna espera un tipo de  entero y tu le estas pasando un string

Comment: Asi es, es lo que no logro comprender ya que cuando cambio la longitrud del campos de la base de datos donde trae ese dato de number(11) a number(19) ya no me manda el error. Trato de convertirlo de Int32 a Int16, int32, decimal, double y me sigue mandando error

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente puede encontrar la solucion.
Cambie el tipo de dato de los campos de mi bd de number a to_char y finalmente en el codigo de tenerlo asi:

```
dRow[3] = string.Format("{0:######0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[3].ToString()) / 100.0);
```

lo deje así:

```
dRow[3] = string.Format("{0:######0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dRow[3]) / 100.0);
```